# Why can this AngularJS directive on jsFiddle not find jQuery-UI?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, jsfiddle

I am trying to get an AngularJS directive that uses jQuery-UI to work in jsfiddle.

- jQuery-UI works fine when used directly
- AngularJS works
- but the directive reports: "element.datepicker is not a function"

**What do I need to do to get jQuery-UI to work inside the directive in jsFiddle?**

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/oqo2xv3e/1

HTML

```
<div ng-app="mainApp">
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <div>{{message}}</div>
        <input id="normal" type="text" />
        <input id="startDate" type="text" ng-model="date" jqdatepicker />
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
angular.module('mainApp', [])
.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'test111';
    $('#normal').datepicker();
})
.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'DD, d  MM, yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    scope.date = date;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your directive with $()..

Because jQuery loads after angular so by default angular picks jqLite.

or loads jQuery first in script tag the angularjs.. you select angular from default lib in fiddle and add jQuery as external.

```
$(element).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'DD, d  MM, yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    scope.date = date;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
```